# Plotting training run loss and metrics only from nth epoch onwards

Tags: r, keras, visualization

Depending on the data, a training run of a keras model in RStudio can look like this.

[image]

I'd like not to plot the first few iterations so the differences of the consecutive epochs are legible. Is there any way to do that in R?

I tried simply stop after a few epochs and then restarting, so the second plot would start at where I stopped after the first epoch. That works but it's not really convenient, in  particular, if there are a lot of options passed to `fit`, there is a lot of code duplication.

Alternatively, it would be nice if the `plot` method for a fitted model could do the same, but I could not figure it out. Any help appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

after the model is fit you could convert the history object to a data frame and perform manipulations on it prior to plotting:

```
library(tidyverse)
as.data.frame(history) %>%
  filter(epoch > 3) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x = epoch, y = value, color = data)) +
  geom_smooth(aes(x = epoch, y = value, color = data)) +
  facet_wrap(~metric, nrow = 2, scales = "free")
```

[image]

I am unsure (meaning I have no clue) how to modify the online plot to output after a certain epoch.

reproducible example:

```
library(keras)

mnist <- dataset_mnist()
train_images <- mnist$train$x
train_labels <- mnist$train$y

train_images <- array_reshape(train_images, c(60000, 28*28))
train_images <- train_images / 255

train_labels <- to_categorical(train_labels)

network <- keras_model_sequential() %>%
  layer_dense(units = 256,
              activation = "relu",
              input_shape = c(28 * 28)) %>%
  layer_dropout(0.3) %>%
  layer_dense(units = 256,
              activation = "relu") %>%
  layer_dropout(0.3) %>%
  layer_dense(units = 10, activation = "softmax")

network %>% compile(
  optimizer = "rmsprop",
  loss = "categorical_crossentropy",
  metrics = c("accuracy")
)

history <- network %>% fit(train_images,
                           train_labels,
                           epochs = 15,
                           batch_size = 128,
                           validation_split = 0.2)
```